# $timeout.cancel not working

Tags: angularjs, timeout

I am trying to cancel $timeout in the code snippet shown below, but it doesn't seems to be working.

```
            var trial=1;
        $scope.trialTimeout = $timeout(countdownTime,0);

        function countdownTime(){
            $timeout(function(){
                trial++;
                console.log("countdownTime");
                if(trial>2)
                    {
                        callMe();
                    }
                countdownTime();
            },1000)
        }

        function callMe(){
            console.log("This "+$timeout.cancel($scope.trialTimeout));
            //$timeout.cancel(trialTimeout);

        }
```

When I log`$timout.cancel($scope.trialTimeout)` it returns false which means that its not cancelling the the timeout. The $scope.trialTimeout gives a promise object but still, its unable to cancel the timeout.

Comment: I'm not sure if this [works](http://plnkr.co/edit/bFiqVYkyn3sQKmJM8JD2?p=preview) for you.

Comment: @Satej S I found the solution, but I am confused why is it so. The problem is I am trying to call "callMe()"  from $timeout and it gives me false, instead if I call it out of the $timeout it would give me "true" why so?

I've attache a plunker which demonstrates the same 

https://plnkr.co/edit/7BCI8YH3JapXjYhZGdoX

Comment: I came across a few answers that performed the cancel inside the timeout, but couldn't find any working version of the same.It is weird.